# Do memcache clients of different languages hash the same way?

Tags: java, php, memcached

We would like to some processing in a Java application, store the results in our pool of memcache servers, and read it back using memcache in PHP.

This is easy enough to try, but I though I would ask and see if anyone else has done this.

As long as both the Java and PHP clients connect to the same pool of memcache servers, will both clients hash to the same server location making retrieval from PHP possible?

Comment: Doing this just seems like a bad idea to me...

Comment: +1 Excellent question. Bad idea? Not at all. Split language environments are a pretty common scenario.

Comment: Can you elaborate?
Conceptually you are just writing data to a spot in memory from 2 different languages... not that different from writing to the same database from 2 different languages.

Comment: @PAS: when using a single memcached server there shouldn't be any problem; but when you use several servers, the usual method is to first do a simple hash on the key to pick the server. this allows you to distribute the data and load without any special code on the server.  but that also means that different client implementations could pick different servers for the same key.

Comment: Javier: That's exactly why he asked this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Not all clients hash the same way.  As evidence of this, you'll see that some clients offer "consistent hashing", while others don't.

In short, memcached clients are allowed to use any hashing algo they please.  There is no official standard.

The PHP client supports [a variety of hashing algorithms](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php) -- so it may be possible to configure it to use the same algo your Java library uses (it looks like there are several out there -- which are you using?).  But you'll want to test heavily, obviously.

Comment: Hmmm interesting - what about Java and PHP in particular?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility to allow cross-language access would be to not rely on the language serialization but store objects in JSON format, as String of text.

Personally, I use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for Java and the json_encode, json_decode in PHP.

Comment: Thanks - yes that is another part of the problem, but first you need to make sure all clients hash the same way so you are only storing data once.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, the key.. well I didn't try the PHP memcached yet, but with Java when you put an object in the cache you explicitely give it a name, so for instance if I say an Object of Type Person with Id 232, I would call the key "Person-232". If you want you can prepend your application name "YourApp-Person-232" and hash everything with SHA1 or MD5. Here is how to generate a Java SHA1 that is the same as the PHP one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769007/can-you-get-this-same-java-sha-1-in-php-please/4769087#4769087

Answer (score 0):

pylibmc

```
import pylibmc

mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True,
                   behaviors={"tcp_nodelay": True,
                               "ketama": True})

key="someKey"
i=0
while True:
    #mc.set(key, str(i))
    value = mc.get(key)
    print(value)
    sleep(1)
    i+=1
```