# Convert SHA1 Hash in PHP to JAVA Code

Tags: java, php, sha1

Hey guys i have a Problem, i must convert PHP to Java...

The Php Function creates a sha1 hash in raw format and encode it.

```
strtolower(urlencode(sha1("asfasfasdf", true)));
```

OUT: `%bep%c3%9cc%dc%e4%89%f6n%0cw%fb%a3%95%ba%d8%c9r%82`

In java i tried:

```
public static String buildIdentity(String identity) {
        try {
            return URLEncoder.encode(toSHA1(identity.getBytes())).toLowerCase();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String toSHA1(byte[] convertme) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        MessageDigest md = null;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.update(convertme);
            byte[] res = md.digest();
            return new String(res);
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


System.out.println(Utils.buildIdentity("asfasfasdf"));
```

but the Output of this is: `%ef%bf%bdp%c3%9cc%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bdn%0cw%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bdr%ef%bf%bd`

please help me :(

**Solution Found!**

```
public static String buildIdentity(String identity) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode( new String(toSHA1(identity.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")), "ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-1").toLowerCase();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static byte[] toSHA1(byte[] convertme){
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(convertme);
        return md.digest();
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769007/can-you-get-this-same-java-sha-1-in-php-please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new String(byte[])` uses the platform default encoding to convert bytes to characters. For me, it works, if you return `new String(res, "iso-8859-1");` from your `toSHA1` method. This should be good, as "the first 256 code points were made identical to the content of ISO-8859-1 so as to make it trivial to convert existing western text." (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Origin_and_development)).

But this involves unnecessary conversion to and from string. Rather, I will use the [`URLCodec`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/URLCodec.html) class from apache commons or copy-paste [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/ConvertabytearraytoaURLencodedstring.htm), if you don't want to add dependencies.

The default encoding problem applies as well to `identity.getBytes()` call: you should specify encoding here. It might work now, but if you deploy to production server, it might not work.

Fixed code using `URLCodec`:

```
public static String buildIdentity(String identity) {
    try {
        return new String(new URLCodec().encode(toSHA1(identity.getBytes("utf-8"))), "iso-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // should never happen, utf-8 and iso-8859-1 support is required by jvm specification. In any case, we rethrow.
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static byte[] toSHA1(byte[] convertme) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(convertme);
        return md.digest();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(buildIdentity("asfasfasdf"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ignoring Java character encoding issues. In the `buildIdentity` method you call `getBytes` on a String without an argument, so the default character encoding for your platform is used. This may cause a problem or not, depending on your platform; to get reproducible results across platforms you need to specify the encoding, such a `identity.getBytes("UTF-8")`.

In the `toSHA1` method you invoke the constructor `new String(res)` without specifying an encoding. Here things most likely go wrong. If your the character encoding of your operating system is different from `ISO-8859-1`, some of the bytes will be replaced with a character that has a different numerical value than the original byte, and when you then encode it using `URLEncoder.encode`, you will not get the result you expected. So instead, use `new String(res, "ISO-8859-1")`.

It also seems that the hash generated by Java is longer than the one generated by PHP. However, if the encodings are correct, they should both *start* with the same string, and you should be able to invoke `substring` the get the proper number of characters to encode.

Comment: hmm its not only substring it, please see new code and output