# I am integrating an android API where stuck to generate xwsse token with the following case

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sha1

I am integrating a API in my android application, where stuck to generate XWSSE token with the following case:

**From PHP:**

1. Token
2. username

**Android:**

1. Timestamp
2. 10 digit random number
3. concat both
4. SHA 1 generation.
5. Making this SHA1 uppercase which gives us NONCE.
6. Nonce + Timestamp + token which we have received are again concat
7. Base64 Conversion.
8. SHA1 generation again.  *(Currently its getting 40 characters result (It should be binary with 20 characters))*
9. Encode in base64. *(This will get a **PasswordDigest**, which should be 28 characters, we are getting 56 character)*

Can anyone suggest what can be done here to get 28 character of PasswordDigest   ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Base64.encodeToString()` function to solve your problem, see this answer for more details

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4769110/5427353

You can create function like this to get exact result what you want as password digest

```
private fun getSHA1(type: String, input: String): String {
     val bytes = input.toByteArray() //input should be (nonce + created + password)
     val md = MessageDigest.getInstance(type) //type should be "SHA-1".
     val digest = md.digest(bytes) // This returns the same string of bytes as $digest = sha1($input, true);

     var passwordDigest = Base64.encodeToString(digest,Base64.DEFAULT) //This returns 28 character password digest. same as base64_encode(sha1($input, true));

     return passwordDigest;
}
```

Comment: Does this returns 28 character `passworddigest` ? Let me try.