# php memcached enyim client flag problem

Tags: c#, php, memcached, flags, collision

I am trying to use memcached with both a php (memcached) and C# (enyim) client.
I have a scenario where I want to CAS a value in php. To do this I am using the following code:

```
$memcached = new Memcached;
$memcached->addServer('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
$memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION, false); // the enyim client doesn't support compression
do {
    $entries = $memcached->get($theKey, null, $cas);
    if ($memcached->getResultCode() == Memcached::RES_NOTFOUND) {
        $entry = somearray("foo");
        $memcached->add($theKey, $entry);
    } else {
        $entries[] = "bar";
        $memcached->cas($cas, $theKey, $entries);
    }
}
while ($memcached->getResultCode() != Memcached::RES_SUCCESS AND $memcached->getResultCode() != Memcached::RES_END);
```

This works all well and fine to begin with.
But then, when the C# client CAS's the same value it goes wrong.
Php gives a warning at:

```
$entries = $memcached->get($theKey, null, $cas);
```

namely that:

```
 PHP Warning:  Memcached::get(): could not uncompress value in ... at line ...
```

And as a result an infinite loop occurs.

Now I tried to get the key from the memcached server via telnet and the data was right there.
In php I am also able to SET to this key without a problem.

I noticed one thing: after the php client has SET something, the flag was 0.
Now after the C# client has CAS'd the value, the flag was 274.
Is there some flag collision on the php lib going on? Or is it something else?

If anyone can help me resolve this problem I'd be gratefull!

lordstyx

[EDIT]

Well then. Since this question isn't getting an answer let me put it differently.
Is there a way to stop the C# client from setting flag 274?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Woah this was almost a year ago. See the answer I posted, because it involves some editing.

Comment: @GRaecuS Forgot to mention your name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I eventually found an answer to my problem. It might not help all of you, because I switched from the Enyim to the BeIT memcached client (http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/)

Now to make the BeIT client compatible with the php client you have to change Serializer.cs
In the enum SerializedType I changed the number of "String" to 0 and ByteArray to 2, which gave this:

```
internal enum SerializedType : ushort
{
    ByteArray   = 2,
    Object      = 1,
    String      = 0, //mod: turned around the numbers for String and ByteArray so it is compatible with php client
    Datetime    = 3,
    ....
```

I believe I went with BeIT because I couldn't find or figure out how the flags worked in the Enyim client. If you understand how it work though, I'm sure that you can change that client in a same manner

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, mixing languages/platforms with memcached is a bad idea. See [another question on similar topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895567/do-memcache-clients-of-different-languages-hash-the-same-way)

Comment: Well, I am only using one memcached server. I serialize the variables with JSON and furthermore, if I have both languages set a value one after the other to the same key, I notice that the value changes (when looking at it via telnet). The C# client can also read anything that php set in the cache. Perhaps the flag is causing some collision in the php lib, but if that's a problem I can maybe find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

For the record.  Since the library is open source, then its possible to modify.

In the class Enyim.Caching.Memcached.DefaultTranscoder, change the function

```
    public static uint TypeCodeToFlag(TypeCode code)
    {
        return (uint)((int)code | 0x0100);
    }
```

to

```
    public static uint TypeCodeToFlag(TypeCode code)
    {
        if (code == TypeCode.String)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return (uint)((int)code | 0x0100);
    }
```

274 = TypeCode.String | 0x0100

Since i don't know the memcache protocol then i don't know whats doing.  However, php's memcache requires 0, so i set to zero when the variable defined is a string.

ps: beitmemcached hasn't be updated for a long while.